# Error en proyecto de Spring Boot: Error starting ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, spring-security

Tengo un problema con SpringBoot en un proyecto personal que estoy haciendo en Visual Studio Code para poder aprender el lenguaje, el error es al implementar la parte de seguridad, por alguna razón este error impide que se despliegue la aplicación y por lo tanto no puedo ver el login, el error se produce en SecurityConfiguration. El error que aparece es este:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
08:24 ERROR 18740 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 



***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field usuarioServicio in com.example.demo4.security.SecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.example.demo4.service.UsuarioServiceImpl' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

Mi clase SecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

@Autowired
private UsuarioServiceImpl usuarioServicio;

PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder =http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        builder.userDetailsService(usuarioServicio).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        authenticationManager = builder.build();
        http.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);

        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
        http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/registro", "/js/","/css/", "/img/")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated());
        //http.exceptionHandling(exc -> exc.authenticationEntryPoint(null))
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean 
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider  authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(usuarioServicio);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }
}
```

Mi clase UsuarioServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class UsuarioServiceImpl implements UsuarioService {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
   
    @Autowired
    private UsuarioDao usuarioDao;

    @Override
    public Usuario guardar(UsuarioRegistroDTO registroDTO) {
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario(registroDTO.getNombre(),
        registroDTO.getApellido(), registroDTO.getEmail(), 
        passwordEncoder.encode(registroDTO.getPassword()), 
        Arrays.asList(new Rol("ROLE_USER")));
        return usuarioDao.save(usuario);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Usuario usuario = usuarioDao.findByEmail(username);
        if(usuario == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuario o password invalidos");
        }
        return new User(usuario.getEmail(), usuario.getPassword(), mapearAutoridadesRoles(usuario.getRoles()));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapearAutoridadesRoles(Collection<Rol> roles) {
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getNombre())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Mi clase UsuarioService:

```
public interface UsuarioService extends UserDetailsService{
    public Usuario guardar(UsuarioRegistroDTO registroDTO);
}
```

Mi clase RegistroUsuarioControlador:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registro")
public class RegistroUsuarioControlador {
    
    @Autowired
    private UsuarioServiceImpl usuarioServicio;

    @ModelAttribute("usuario")
    public UsuarioRegistroDTO  retornarNuevoUsuarioRegistroDTO() {
        return new UsuarioRegistroDTO();
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String mostrarFormularioDeRegistro(){
        return "registro";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String registrarCuentaDeUsuario(@ModelAttribute("usuario") UsuarioRegistroDTO registroDTO){
        usuarioServicio.guardar(registroDTO);
        return "redirect:/registro?exito";
    }
    
    


}
```

Mi pom.xml es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo4</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo4</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-rsa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>


 </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Este es el Demo4Application:

```
package com.example.demo4;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo4Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo4Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Este es el aplication.properties:

```
server.port=8082
logging.pattern.dateformat=hh:mm
spring.main.banner-mode=off
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

#Mysql conexion
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbd?useSSL=false&serverTimeZone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pswd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

#Mostrar SQL
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.forma_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type-descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

#crear bdd
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create


# security
spring.security.user.name=usuario
spring.security.user.password=psw
```

El árbol de carpetas sería el siguiente:

[image: Carpetas del Proyecto de Spring]

He estado intentando corregirlo con algunas respuestas de preguntas parecidas de aquí, pero por ejemplo poniendo la clase con la etiqueta @Autowired(required=true) en la variable usuarioServicio de tipo UsuarioServiceImpl no lo he conseguido arreglar de hecho mi error se replica también en RegistroUsuarioControlador.java.

También he visto que es probable que la distribución de carpetas no esté bien hecha, pero no se en que fallaría en mi caso. Si necesitáis mas información o que os proporcione mas código os lo puedo adjuntar.

El tutorial que estoy siguiendo lo saque de aquí aunque lo actualicé porque muchas librerías estaban obsoletas:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wTsLRxS3gA

**¿Alguien me puede ayudar a solucionar este error?**

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Esto no creo que vaya a resolver tu error, pero... si estás usando inyección de dependencias (con el @Autowired) y usando interfaces para tus servicios, no tiene sentido declararlo así: `@Autowired private UsuarioServiceImpl usuarioServicio;` porque estás creando una dependencia estricta de ESA implementación específica. Lo correcto sería `@Autowired private UsuarioService usuarioServicio;` y ya SpringBoot decide qué implementación específica inyectarte (aunque en este caso solo tengas una).

Comment: Gracias Benito, ya lo he cambiado.

Comment: tengo este proyecto con spring security por si te sirve https://github.com/carlos033/ServicorRestConJjwt

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Veo dos problemas:

- Las clases anotadas con `@Configuration` son las que definen con (`@Bean`) las dependencias que se pueden inyectar. Si esta clase tiene una dependencia (`@Autowired`), debe existir algo anterior que defina ese *bean* a inyectar.
- Ese bean tiene otras dependencias, que tampoco se instanciarán a tiempo.

Spring gestiona la inyección de dependencias para cada componente de la aplicación. El clásico escenario es tener una clase anotada como @Configuration donde se declaran componentes que pueden ser inyectados en otros o directamente ser puntos de entrada, como los @Controller/@RestController.

Por ejemplo:

```java
@RestController("users")
class UserController {

  @Autowired
  UserService userService;
 
  @GetRequest("/{id})
  User getUserById(@PathVariable int id) { ... }
}


@Configuration
class Config {

  @Bean
  UserService getUserService() {
    return new UserService(...)
  }
}
```

Spring aquí lo que va a hacer es instanciar la clase marcada con @Configuration, simplemente llamando a su constructor, y llamará a cada uno de los métodos anotados con @Bean para obtener instancias de clases que podrán luego ser añadidas a otros componentes. Una vez hecho esto, buscará en el mismo paquete (e hijos) clases marcadas como @Component, @Service, @Repository... etc e intentará instanciarlas, inyectando las dependencias que sean necesarias.

Por tanto, si tu clase de configuración tiene una dependencia, no va a saber cómo inyectarla.

Posible solución:

- Quita el @Autowired a tu clase con @Configuration y pon esa dependencia directamente en el método que la necesita:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain (HttpSecurity http, UsuarioServiceImpl usuarioServicio) throws Exception{
   ...
}
```

De este modo retrasas la necesidad de esa dependencia, Spring la buscará cuando quiera instanciar el SecurityFilterChain, pero la clase de configuración ya estará instanciada.

Comment: El primer punto no lo termino de entender, soy bastante novato en este framework. El segundo si lo he intentado con el @componentScan pero me sigue dando error.

Comment: He añadido una explicación más completa

Comment: Pero la etiqueta SpringBootApplication "incluye" ya ComponentScan y la clase anotada con ella está en la raíz del paquete. ¿No debería instanciar UsuarioServiceImpl? Puede que haya un error previo que impida esta instanciación.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que Spring intenta instanciar la clase antes de hacer el barrido en busca de las dependencias, con lo que aún no ha encontrado dicha clase. He editado de nuevo.

Comment: Buenas, he hecho lo que acabas de editar pero me da el mismo fallo. Si hace falta algún archivo lo puedo actualizar.

Comment: ¿Has quitado el autowired **Y** el atributo de Configuration? El error no puede ser exactamente el mismo

Comment: Si, ya parece que funciona. Todavía tengo errores pero son de distintas índole. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Se me esta produciendo el mismo error en la clase RegistroUsuarioControlador.java que pase, he aplicado lo que dijiste pero en esta clase pero no funciona adecuadamente...no se si el hecho de quitar el controlador y pasarlo por parámetro es la mejor opción creo que el problema es mas profundo.